# Custom List property not being updated from MVC View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm using EF with MVC3.

I have a model with a custom list:

```
public List<MarketingModel> Marketing { get; set; }
```

I initialise this in the constructor as:

```
 this.Marketing = new List<MarketingModel>();
```

I view it in the View:

```
@foreach (MarketingModel m in Model.Marketing)
{

 <td class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(model => m.Name)</td>
 <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => m.Mail)</td>
 <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => m.Email)</td>

}
```

Which populates fine. However when saving the page, it for whatever reason passes Marketing as a null value.

Really stumped on this.

Comment: Take a look at the resulting HTML and check what IDs are generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `foreach` loop.  the `XXXFor` helper methods use expression trees designed to determine the property path to your property from the model.  This property path is used to construct the `name` attribute on the corresponding HTML input elements.

Since you are not consuming the model in your lambda (`model => m.Name` <-- note that you are not using `model`) the property path is incorrect.  Instead, use a `for` loop:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Marketing.Count; i++) 
{
    <td class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Marketing[i].Name)</td>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Marketing[i].Mail)</td>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Marketing[i].Email)</td>
}
```

This way, the entire path to the property is contained in your expression tree (`Model.Marketing[i].Name`) and the corresponding `name` attribute should contain that full path now.  Thus upon saving, the data should now be there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Phil Haack's MVC binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).  It has all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a foreach that sets the new scope to Model.Marketing, your post is confusing MVC binding. I would inspect the HTML created and pay attention to the name attribute for those fields in question. The name has to be the same pattern as the other model properties.

For List/Collection objects you can use an array type of index for specifying the particular item. for example if your field is meant to bind to Model.Marketing.Mail, the name should be similar: "Marketing[2].Mail".

Anytime you dive deeper into the model with a property of a property, you need to adjust the name as shown above, or create a new htmlhelper extension to handle your object so you can use something like @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Marketing), or also you could write a custom model binder in the controller to fix this name matching for you, you will also have access to the Request object in the controller's context that will let you cherry pick out form elements that were posted.

Post your generated html snippets if you still need help.